# Determining scope / context of a method call in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, metaprogramming, decorator, metaclass

I would like to write a decorator for a python class method that can determine if the method was called from a public context or private context.  For example, given the following code

```
def public_check_decorator(f):
    def wrapper(self):
        if self.f is `called publicly`:  # <-- how do I make this line work correctly?
            print 'called publicly'
        else:
            print 'called privately'
        return f(self)
    return wrapper

class C(object):
    @public_check_decorator
    def public_method(self):
        pass

    def calls_public_method(self):
        self.public_method()
```

runtime execution would ideally look something like this:

```
>>> c = C()
>>> c.public_method()
called publicly

>>> c.calls_public_method()
called privately
```

Is there any way to do this in python?  That is, alter the line

```
if self.f is `called publicly`:  # <-- how do I make this line work correctly?
```

to give the desired output?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would you need to do this?

Comment: how do you *define* public? is it, called outside any function? called in a global function? something else? Is there a particular stack you define as a public entry to the function?

Comment: `c.public_method` is the same as `self.public_method` in `calls_public_method`. So what exactly are you trying to check?

Comment: @Blender The short answer--and probably most useful and obvious--is it would let you enforce private scope (or throw some sort or error).  My use, however, is a bit more complicated.  Given a metaclass that allows lazy initialization of the class instance (i.e. delayed call to __init__), trigger the __init__ call only when a "public" method is accessed.  Or, delay until a method is access publicly. Yeah, yeah, I know _my_ use case here sounds dangerous. And it'll likely never see any production code ever. But I think it's an interesting question nonetheless.

Comment: @mhlester Let me clarify private and public. Most accurately for me, private is actually more like _protected_, in the java/c++ form of protected methods.  A public method then is any method that's not protected.

Comment: @thefourtheye My guess(?) is that the solution might somehow use the `inspect` module to look back into the call stack??  There may be other, more efficient ways too.  I realize that the `c` instance and `self` point to the same objects, but their positions in the call stack would have to be different, no?

Comment: @kalefranz But what difference does it make?

Comment: @thefourtheye Python has no native concept of private and public attributes, unlike java and c++. What I'm attempting to do is sort of an end-run around python's looseness here.  Where java just wouldn't given you access to a private method accessed out of scope, I would think there would be _some_ way with decorators to treat one case differently than the other.  Am I still not answering your question?  Put _overly_ simply, I want a way to have public and private methods in python (again, that's __over__ simplified).

Comment: Attempts to turn Python into Java are doomed to failure (and are silly, to boot)

Answer (score 1):

Given the name of the package decides whether a function is being called from a private context or public one:

```
import inspect
import re


def run():
    package_name = '/my_package/'
    p = re.match(r'^.*' + package_name, inspect.stack()[0].filename).group()
    is_private_call = any(re.match(p, frame.filename) is not None for frame in inspect.stack()[1:])
    print(is_private_call)
```

Try running from within the package and then from outside the package!!!
see [inspect.stack()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html)

Answer (score -1):

Some of this seems like trying to swim against the current of "python". Is that appropriate?

Do you know about the double-unscore standard? It makes methods "more private":

```
>>> class C(object):
...    def __hide_me(self):
...        return 11
...    def public(self):
...        return self.__hide_me()
...
>>> c = C()
>>> c.__hide_me()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'C' object has no attribute '__hide_me'
>>> c.public()
11
>>> c._C__hide_me()
11
>>>
```

Is that private enough? And using this technique is pythonic.

Comment: The double underscore and name mangling isn't what I'm after here.  And I'd argue that what I'm trying to do is pythonic at its core.  I want to wrap a class method with another function to influence that method's behavior.  That's what decorators and metaclasses are all about, and what makes them incredibly powerful (and indeed pythonic!).  My comments on my main post can be read to seem like I'm just trying to make a method have private access only; that is an incorrect reading, although it is one potential use case.